# how to represent a cubic polynomal using a simplified equation?

Tags: polynomials

if a quadratic polynomial is represented as,
$$
f(x)=x^TAx+bx+c
$$
**Question:** how to represent a cubic polynomial and a quartic polynomial?

Comment: What does $x^T$ signify?

Comment: **x** is a matrix, such as **x** =[x,y,z]^T

Comment: You would need a cubic form represented by a tensor of order 3 :$f(x)=\sum_{ijk=1}^n d_{ijk}x_ix_jx_k,x=(x_1,\ldots x_n)$

Comment: Could it be represented by a combination of matrices? like quadratic polynomial

Comment: Considering each $d_{ijk}$ could be considered a $1\times 1$ matrix, Cretin2 has already represented it as a combination of matrices. But if you are looking for something without indices like the quadratic expression you give in the question, the answer is no. It requires three indices for full generality, while matrices only have two. And note that your expression actually does have indices, but hides them with a notational convention. You can attempt such conventions with higher order tensors, but they quickly become more messy than the indicial notation.

Comment: You are right. Thanks, Cretin2 and Paul!